# generating sample from binomial distribution and calculate the mean and variance.

Tags: variance

I am trying to calculate the mean and the variance from sample has generated from Binomial distribution .with p=0.1, m=number of trials is 100, n =sample size is 100 and N=nc 10^5.My equation is why the mean and variance sometimes are equal . M=V. about 10%  from the data. 
here is my code

```
nc=10^5
m=100
n=100
p=0.1
for(k in 1:nc){
  b[k,]=rbinom(n,m,p) 
  M=mean(b[k,])
  V=var(b[k,])
  if( M==V){ 
    print(M)
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Is this a math question or a programming question?

Comment: I am thinking that is because of the p is  a very small . when I chaged the to  p=0.3 insteand of 0.1. I did not  get the M=V. which are the mean and variance.

Comment: If you just had three values, they might for example be $12, 6, 9$.  These have mean $9$ and sample ($\frac{1}{n-1}$) variance $9$ and those two values are equal.  These things sometimes happen by chance.  The population mean is $np$ and the population variance $np(1-p)$, which will anyway be close for small $p$

Comment: p=0.1
>   for(k in 1:nc){
      b[k,]=rbinom(n,m,p) 
       M=mean(b[k,])
     V=var(b[k,])
       if( M==V){           print(M)
        }
   }
[1] 10.01
[1] 9.76
[1] 9.76
[1] 9.76
[1] 10.25
[1] 10.01
[1] 10.25
[1] 10.01
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 9.76
[1] 10
[1] 10
[1] 9.76
[1] 10.01
[1] 10
[1] 9.76

Comment: Thank you all for your help. dear Henry, the M and V are not calculated by the formal of binomial distribution .M is  a sample mean (the fist moment ) and V is sample varince too.